# Add an audio file to another audio file at intervals with end result being a new audio file

Tags: php, python, ruby, node.js

how can i add a sound to another audio file at specific intervals of my choosing finally exporting the end result as an mp3 or wav file and what programming language would be best to accomplish this

Comment: Get raw data bits in a list of both audio files using any audio processing library/module concatenate and manipulate raw data bits accordingly.

Comment: ok rajan, i will come back with a reply if this works out. thank you for answering :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub) might be good for this (you will have to install it). You can then do something like:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

main_clip = AudioSegment.from_file('main_clip.wav')
overlay_clip = AudioSegment.from_file('overlay.wav')

interval = 1000  # milliseconds
start_point = 4000  # milliseconds

new_clip = main_clip

for i in range(start_point, len(main_clip), interval):
    new_clip = new_clip.overlay(overlay_clip, position=i)

new_clip.export('new_clip.wav', format='wav')
```

It is a pretty nice high level interface, and can do many other things too. Hope this helped.

Comment: Did you checked whether your code is working or not? You have just overwrited the `function overlay` by creating `overlay variable`.

Comment: i will try it and come back to give you a check if it works, thank you for replying. :)

Comment: I did test it, and this works as I expect (and I think this is what OP is asking for). No I did not overwrite the method `overlay` on the `AudioSegment` object, as my `overlay` variable is in a different scope. But I will change the variable name for clarity.

Comment: your answer worked beautifully. thank you very much.